# Vertica Function Creation issue with flywaydb

Tags: flyway, vertica

Using Vertica 7.1 with flyway 3.2.1 getting errors when creating functions even tried the example from the docs. Almost like it doesn't ignore the first ';' :

code in the .sql file

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION default_to_hello(x VARCHAR) RETURN VARCHAR
AS BEGIN
  -- The body of a SQL function in Vertica must be in the form 'RETURN expression'
  RETURN (CASE WHEN (x IS NOT NULL) THEN x ELSE 'Hello' END);
END;
```

Error reported:

```
Current version of schema "public": 2
Migrating schema "public" to version 3 - test
ERROR: Migration of schema "public" to version 3 failed! Please restore backups and roll back database and code!
ERROR: 
Migration V3__test.sql failed
-----------------------------
SQL State  : 42601
Error Code : 4856
Message    : [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near "EOL"
Location   : /opt/flywaydb/sql/V3__test.sql (/opt/flywaydb/sql/V3__test.sql)
Line       : 1
Statement  : CREATE or replace FUNCTION default_to_hello(x VARCHAR) RETURN VARCHAR
AS BEGIN
  -- The body of a SQL function in Vertica must be in the form 'RETURN expression'
  RETURN (CASE WHEN (x IS NOT NULL) THEN x ELSE 'Hello' END)
```

Has any one else had this happen or am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like it might be lack of support for the "OR REPLACE" option, removed that and it works fine.

Comment: Are you sure it needs to go in the `public` schema? Have you tried running it manually in Vertica?

Comment: This was just a sand box test using the database admin account against the public schema for testing. The script works fine in vertica but flyway doesn't seem to support the "or replace" option at this time.

Comment: @blitzkriegva Flyway merged the change into the 4.0 milestone and of course you can backport the patch into the current version.

Answer (score 1):

Flyway's `VerticaStatementBuilder` does not support `OR REPLACE`. You can see the [code here](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/dbsupport/vertica/VerticaStatementBuilder.java) for how that parse (it leaves no room for deviation).

```
    if (statementStart.startsWith("CREATE FUNCTION")) {
        if (line.startsWith("BEGIN") || line.endsWith("BEGIN")) {
            insideBeginEndBlock = true;
        }

        if (line.endsWith("END;")) {
            insideBeginEndBlock = false;
        }
    }
```

I submitted a pull request for it and it was merged for Flyway 4.0.

Comment: hahahahaha , was downvoted because Kermit is a hater, Kermit = downvote rain kkkkk

Comment: @Up_One It's not easy... being green.

Comment: @Up_One Please see my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265445/vertica-function-creation-issue-with-flywaydb/33275680#comment54385999_33275680]) on the answer I downvoted. I'd also recommend seeing the [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on how to answer.

Comment: @Kermit - i really wanna meet you, you are funny :). Relax were are just joking. But you need to relax, not all of us read the guide, we are just mortals :)

Comment: @Up_One I'll be in Ireland in January. Let's meet then?

Comment: A bit far for me ! i am down under now :). when you are in Melbourne let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your function works, it is some hidden character or something like this.

- i managed to reproduce the error while trying to execute it in DbVis.

But in vsql client on the Vertica nodes is working fine.

```
dbadmin=> CREATE or replace FUNCTION default_to_hello(x VARCHAR) RETURN VARCHAR
dbadmin-> AS BEGIN
dbadmin->   -- The body of a SQL function in Vertica must be in the form 'RETURN expression'
dbadmin->   RETURN (CASE WHEN (x IS NOT NULL) THEN x ELSE 'Hello' END);
dbadmin-> END;
CREATE FUNCTION
dbadmin=> select default_to_hello('Working');
 default_to_hello
------------------
 Working
(1 row)

dbadmin=> select default_to_hello(null);
 default_to_hello
------------------
 Hello
(1 row)
```

Comment: Checked it twice no hidden characters, the issue is in flyway not recognizing the "OR REPLACE" and parses the code wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a parsing bug. Please file an issue in the Flyway issue tracker. Pull request also welcome.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it doesn't solve the question. In this case, your answer should be a comment or provide an alternative solution.